# Win32:trojan-gen virus exe installed

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, virus, anti-virus, avg-antivirus

I ran fake exe as i thought it was another program. After deep scanning with AVG, it located a win32:trojan-gen exe, moved it to quarantine and deleted. After scaning again, shows no malware. I am still worried if it's completely removed, should I do additional steps?

Answer (score 0):

"win32:trojan-gen exe" is a fairly generic warning about an executable program (exe) that *could* be malware, but has not yet actually been run, nor done any harm, yet. I.E., it appears AVG intercepted it before harm was done.

That said, if you believe that there *could be* malware on your machine, it does no harm to run a free, third-party malware scanner, such as [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/malwarebytes-anti-malware/).

Before running or installing *any* third-party application, whether an anti-malware suite or some other application, [check it in VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload), which submits it to 60 or more reputable malware scanners. [If only one or two flags are raised, I might consider them perhaps false positives.]

Comment: based on your story, I strongly recommend backing up your content and nuking the install from orbit. once a system that has no active response enabled has been confirmed infected, you just cannot trust it ever again. all your AV detected was the installer. whatever it did to your system is still there, and if you run with admin capabilities the malware can hide in ways no AV system being installed now could detect.